# Oracle SQL Developer 2.1 - Filter not working when using JTDS extension (v1.5 still working)

Tags: sql-server, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've upgraded to Oracle SQL Developer 2.1 and installed JTDS extension to work with SQL Server.

But when I open the Data tab of a table, I cannot use filter features.

I've check with an Oracle db, it works fine!
Is there anyone get this trouble?

Any suggestions are welcome!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same behaviour when using mySQL JDBC driver. I don't know , if there is a feature , or bug.

Comment: Apparently, more than 4 years later, this feature is still not available for SQL Server using oracle SQL Developer 4.0.1.14 and jtds-1.3.1.